# What is DataDir in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datadirectory

I know the usage of @@datadir in MySQL queries such as;

```
Select @@datadir;
```

It outputs something like that:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\data\
```

But what the heck is it? What does it do? Is there any special meaning about directory data of MySQL? Why is there a specific command in MySQL like @@datadir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the directory where your database files are stored.

It can be changed [when installing the server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html#option_mysql_install_db_datadir) or before running it and is of special meaning for larger servers, e.g. clustered MySQL servers running on multiple servers.

Comment: So why does developers need to use @@datadir command in sql queries? Do you know that?

Comment: According to your statement, then we can say that all database data take place in the single path that @@datadir shows. So in terms of hackers, probably it is important to find this path in order to download all database files and dump all critical data. Okay, thank you for your answer.